# unable to pip-install pyravendb (enum 0.4.6 error)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, ravendb

I'm trying to install the pyravendb "lib" in my python3 installation on ubuntu 16.04. (pip install pyravendb)
It seems to be a dependency error, yet its using the one that comes with the lib ( collecting enum 0.4.6 from pyravendb ).

The stack error is the following :

```
pip install pyravendb
Collecting pyravendb
  Using cached pyravendb-1.3.0.zip
Collecting pycrypto>=2.6.1 (from pyravendb)
  Using cached pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.9.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pyravendb)
Collecting inflector>=2.0.11 (from pyravendb)
  Using cached Inflector-2.0.11.tar.gz
Collecting enum>=0.4.6 (from pyravendb)
  Using cached enum-0.4.6.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
        import setuptools.version
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
        import pkg_resources
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
        import platform
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/platform.py", line 117, in <module>
        import sys, os, re, subprocess
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 364, in <module>
        import signal
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/signal.py", line 4, in <module>
        from enum import IntEnum as _IntEnum
    ImportError: cannot import name 'IntEnum'
    Error in sys.excepthook:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
        from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
        from apport.report import Report
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 12, in <module>
        import subprocess, tempfile, os.path, re, pwd, grp, os, time
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 364, in <module>
        import signal
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/signal.py", line 4, in <module>
        from enum import IntEnum as _IntEnum
    ImportError: cannot import name 'IntEnum'

    Original exception was:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
        import setuptools.version
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
        import pkg_resources
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
        import platform
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/platform.py", line 117, in <module>
        import sys, os, re, subprocess
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 364, in <module>
        import signal
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/signal.py", line 4, in <module>
        from enum import IntEnum as _IntEnum
    ImportError: cannot import name 'IntEnum'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ta1arld3/enum/
```

Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved in this commit:

https://github.com/ravendb/RavenDB-Python-Client/commit/67b15a75d477765a074ba58086b997bb174b8c27

Wrong package dependency.